# WebSocket for message notification is not working for some browser

Tags: playframework, java-websocket

I have implementing message notification system in play 2.4 using WebSocket. When i tested this on chrome **Version 48.0.2564.116 (64-bit)** (windows 8 and mac) + mozilla (windows 8 and mac), it's working. But when i tested it on windows 7 chrome **Version 49.0.2623.110**  and Firefox **Version 45.0.1** connection is established but notification is not showing on browser even connection is alive.

I tried to find the problem whether it's related to os but i didn't get any solution. Can any one help ?

Comment: It is probably more related to browser version. Please, edit your question to add browser versions for both success and failure scenarios. Also, take a look at http://caniuse.com/#feat=websockets

Comment: I agree with @marcospereira. If your browser supports WebSockets you can find in http://caniuse.com/#feat=websockets. Especially older IE don't.

Comment: Hi @marcospereira i have update browser version. And i also checked my browser version supports socket.

Comment: Are you seeing some error (client side or server side)?

Comment: No, i am not getting any error. But i saw one stranger behavior, whenever i closed my server i received all the messages on browser that i server has publish.